# Make an iPhone-only Qt application

Tags: ios, qt, qt5, qtquick2

I want to target only iPhone with my Qt-based iOS app (so it will run on iPad in smaller format). I tried two ways to do this:

First: On the Internet it's suggested that I put the following lines in Info.plist:

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
    <integer>1</integer>
</array>
```

This might have worked in earlier versions of Xcode, but Xcode 6 seems to ignore it.

Second: I run qmake to generate *.xcodeproj file for my project and opened it in Xcode. This way I'm able to successfully run and deploy my app from Xcode. I can also see its device family setting (Universal by default), but when I try to change it, Xcode crashes.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't modify Info.plist by hand. Set the device family through the Info tab on Xcode.

Comment: As you can see in my post, I already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this turns out to be the second one, but a bug in Xcode 6.3 causes it to crash:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45966

The comments below the bug report suggest a workaround, which is installing Xcode 6.2.